# how to stop particles from moving off stage, Actionscript random particle generator

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Below is some code for a random particle generator. I want to change it so the particles only move a small distance before stopping and not disappearing. As it is now, they keep moving until they go off stage. I'm new to Actionscript so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
var particleArray:Array = new Array();
var maxParticles:Number = 50000;

function addParticle(e:Event)
{
    var Symbol:Symbol3 = new Symbol3();
    Symbol.alpha = Math.random() * .8 + .2;
    Symbol.scaleX = Symbol.scaleY = Math.random() * .8 + .2;
    Symbol.xMovement = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    Symbol.yMovement = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    Symbol.x = mouseX;
    Symbol.y = mouseY;
    particleArray.push(Symbol);
    addChild(Symbol);
    Symbol.cacheAsBitmap = true;

    if (particleArray.length >= maxParticles)
    {
        removeChild(particleArray.shift());
    }

    Symbol.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveParticle);
}

function moveParticle(e:Event)
{
    e.currentTarget.x += e.currentTarget.xMovement;
    e.currentTarget.y += e.currentTarget.yMovement;
}

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(50);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addParticle);
myTimer.start();
```

Comment: This is code for a tutorial i found, i have loads of other features added in my actual program but don't think its relevant to this problem, wanted to keep it simple. this is the only thing i'm trying to do that i cant figure out. here is the link to the tutorial : http://www.schoolofflash.com/2008/03/flash-cs3-particle-effect/4/

Comment: I was thinking if i only called the moveParticle function a few times, i have tired to remove the event listener after a while loop iterates a number of times but doesn work probably because it is added again each time addParticle is called. As i said im new to ActionScript and flash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to remove the event listener after a number executions:

```
function addParticle(e:Event)
{
    var Symbol:Symbol3 = new Symbol3();
    Symbol.alpha = Math.random() * .8 + .2;
    Symbol.scaleX = Symbol.scaleY = Math.random() * .8 + .2;
    Symbol.xMovement = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    Symbol.yMovement = Math.random() * 10 - 5;

    // set the number of times this instance can move. 
    // Using a randomly generated number here
    Symbol.movementCount = int(Math.random() * 10); 
    Symbol.x = mouseX;
    Symbol.y = mouseY;
    particleArray.push(Symbol);
    addChild(Symbol);
    Symbol.cacheAsBitmap = true;

    if (particleArray.length >= maxParticles)
    {
        removeChild(particleArray.shift());
    }

    Symbol.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveParticle);
}

function moveParticle(e:Event)
{
    e.currentTarget.x += e.currentTarget.xMovement;
    e.currentTarget.y += e.currentTarget.yMovement;

    // decrement your move count, and then check to see if it's hit zero
    e.currentTarget.movementCount--;
    if(e.currentTarget.movementCount <=0)
    {
        // if so, remove the event listener
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveParticle);
    }
}
```